# How to filter out Frames of several applications within the same JVM

Tags: java, awt, classloader, frame

I have an application manager that loads and runs application jars in a single JVM. It isolates each jar to its own classloader. The manager communicates with the children through sockets for data and configuration purposes. The trouble that I am having is that I want to be able to use the getFrames call within each application for geometry save/restore and it always returns all frames within the JVM for every application running in that JVM. Is there a way to filter the results per application? I tried filtering based on classloader but the Frames classloaders are always null.

Comment: *"I have an application manager that loads and runs application jars"*  Do you control the code of the apps. being launched? *"use the getFrames call within each application for geometry save/restore"*  What 'geometry' exactly?  DYM the size/location of the frames?

Comment: I do not control the actual code of the applications.The apps instatiate my framework that gives me the ability to issue the Frames.getFrames() within the application. Geometry being XY Width Height. It saves this data off so it can restore a previous session of these applications.

Answer (score 1):

Since you give only few details, it's hard to say what could be wrong. Some comments:

1. It's generally not a good idea to run several Java apps in a single VM. Logging frameworks and DB drivers, for example, install global hooks in the VM so unloading them becomes impossible. Consider to run each app in its own VM. Use the system properties to determine the parameters which you need. [Here is some code](http://java.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java) that should get you started.
2. If running each app in their own VM isn't an option, how about talking to each app and make it "register" itself with the app server? [Web servers use standardized listeners](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets4.html) for this purpose. That way, apps could tell you which frames/config values to save.
3. The `classLoader` property of a class can never be null - A class loader is the only way to create a Class instance in Java.

Comment: I was trying to improve performance by running multiple apps in single JVM.  I do not have control over the code of the applications but the apps do register with the application manager using a framework that I do control. This framework is what sets up the sockets both server and client. I was trying to scrape the frame info dynamically and limit the amount of extra work the developers of the apps would have to do.

Comment: If you a have a java.awt.Frame call frame and you do a frame.getClass.getClassloader(), it will come back null. At least in my current experiments.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: :-/ ... Aha... from the [javadoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader): "Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader." Now it makes sense since the Frame comes from the parent class loader which usually is the bootstrap class loader.

Answer (score 1):

I assume getFrames() queries some global collection. The only way to isolate such a globally accessible library is to have each application load is own copy of the Frames library (so its not globally accessible)  This makes it harder to call getFrames() ;)

Comment: I was refering to Frames.getFrames() of the java.awt.Frame class. When running muliple apps in a single JVM, it will return all of the frames of all of the applications. (which is kinda nifty unless you want to filter based on application)

Comment: I wouldn't run multiple GUI applications in the same JVM. But if you did, I would have the JFrames be a sub-class with a method which tells you which application that frame is for.  You can then search by application by matching the result of this method.